# How to get Values from Yahoo Finance XHR's Complex Object in Google Apps Script

Tags: object, google-apps-script, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to pull historical quarterly revenue data from Yahoo Finance.  Its default "Annual" [webpage](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/JPM/financials?p=JPM) is updated by selecting "Quarterly" option button, but its URL is still same.  It appears that "Quarterly" option only updates the screen behind.  So I was not able to pull quarterly data from the URL, but annual data only.  Tracking of its XHR request, I figured out its source header, by the following codes below.  Now I face another challenge on how to extract quarterlyTotalRevenue from its complex object, because of my lack of understanding about object handling.  What I finally want to get is an array, something like this.
[image]
How can I do that?   Thank you for any help!

```
function test() {
  var ticker = 'JPM';
  var url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/'
    + ticker + '?lang=en-US&region=US&symbol=' + ticker + '&padTimeSeries=true&type=' + '%2cquarterlyTotalRevenue' +
    '%2c&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1672016399&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com';
  var obj = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  var obj = JSON.parse(obj);  //Convert strings to object
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var obj = ### // Please set your value.

var valeus = [["asOfDate", "raw"], ...obj.timeseries.result[0].quarterlyTotalRevenue.map(({ asOfDate, reportedValue: { raw } }) => [asOfDate, raw])];
var res = valeus[0].map((_, c) => valeus.map(r => r[c]));

// return res; // If you want to use this as a custom function, please use this.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, 2).setValues(res);
```

- In this modification, the values are put to the active sheet. If you want to use this script as a custom function, please return the values like `return res;`.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, you’re a hero to me.  It works perfectly.  Everyday I’m learning from you.  Now I understood very well how to handle objects from your codes.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: actually I realize that if I delete my manually structured obj and use the obj directly from the url, it doesn’t work. Could you check how the original obj from the url is structured? Sorry for my lack of basic understanding.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, from googling, I learned how to convert URL's output strings to an object.  I added  [var obj = JSON.parse(obj)] in the first post.   Now your script is working well directly with the URL output.   Thanks to Tanaike!